# Modify keyword not working Drools

Tags: drools, jbpm

I am testing infinite loops using Modify keyword.

But it is not re triggering the rule.

**Rule 1:**

```
rule "Entitle for promotion"

when
$i: EmployeeFinancialFact(rating==Rating.ONE.getRating())
then
  PromotionFact $promotion=new PromotionFact($i.getEmpID(),$i.getEmpName());
  insert($promotion);
end
```

**Rule 2:**

```
rule "Print EmployeeFinancialFact name entitled for promotion"

when
$p:  PromotionFact()
then
modify($p) {setSentForApproval(true);}
end
```

I am expecting RHS of rule 2 will re-trigger the rule 2 again but it is getting fired only once.

Can anyone please tell me the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable property reactive in Kmodule.xml in Drools 7 by adding following lines:

```
<configuration>
  <property key="drools.propertySpecific" value="ALLOWED"/>
</configuration>
```

Comment: why does this need to be disabled?

Comment: If property reactivity is set to enabled (the default since Drools 7), the rule will be fired again only for objects where an attribute named in the LHS of the rule was changed by the RHS. Since no attribute in the LHS of the rule was changed for this object, it won't fire again. If you want to disable reactivity *only* for this rule, add @watch(*) at the end   of the LHS of rule #2. Then any modification of a PromotionFact should cause the rule to run again.

Answer (score 1):

The first obvious question would be if you are sure your rules are indeed getting executed (sounds like a silly question, but it has solved many many issues here in SO).

Some other relevant questions are:

- which version of Drools are you using?
- Is `PromotionFact` a java class? or a defined declaration in your DRL?
- Do you know if *[Property Reactive](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.0.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_property_reactivity_enabled_by_default)* is enabled in your kbase? It used to be disabled in versions < 7, but since version 7 is enabled by default.

Hope it helps,

Comment: 1.Yes Rules are getting fired.I put the SYSOUT to confirm this.
2. Yes PromotionFact is a Java class.
3. PromotionFact  is not annotated with property reactive.
4. Drools version is 7.4.1.final

Comment: I guess then that the "issue" is that *Property Reactive* is enabled. Try to disable it.

Comment: Yup, you are champ . Property Reactive was the issue.